# I cannot make stem search in solr

Tags: solr

I added a stem filter to Solr. Although I can see the filter on "admin/analysis" interface. I cannot make a search on solritas page of solr with stems.

For example: When i write "jumping" on solritas text box for searching, I am expecting the results that will cover all words that "jump jumping jumped". But my results cover exact word which i wrote.

As a summary i cannot make stem search on solritas, although i added to solr a stem filter. In other words i can make just exact match search on solr.

Can anybody help me?

Tayfun

Comment: You'll have to add the relevant part of your schema, and the output from the analysis page with the indexed term and the query term together with the processing pipeline. Remember that you also have to reindex after adding the filter to get the proper stemmed versions in your index.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you also applied stemming query time. As stemming doesn't stores all the three forms. but it converts all the three words to one. i.e if you have jump, jumping, jumped than it will store jump for all the three words.